# Angular JS adding the character length together of two inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a app in Angular JS, I am trying to figure out how to add the two character counts lengths together(from text area inputs) as below, but this does not work:

```
$scope.what=[];
$scope.why=[];

$scope.characters = $scope.what.length + $scope.why.length;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want sum of two array length?

Answer (score 2):

`characters` should be a function:

```
$scope.characters = function(){
   return $scope.what.length + $scope.why.length;
}
```

Then in your HTML/view call the function:

```
{{ characters() }}
```

---

The way you have it setup at the moment the `characters` object will initialise on build and will remain static.

Comment: is there a way to put a limit on this? i.e maximum 2000 characters?

Comment: @Sole A limit on what? The inputs? We would need to see more of your code for this, it would probably be better as a different question.

Comment: Actually that didn't that only returns the first character count?

Comment: @Sole How are `what` and `why` populated? These are defined as empty arrays not `input` elements.

Comment: So I am using UU-bootstrap, these are text area inputs, that then get binded into another div for display... via expressions i.e  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="what[$index]" ng-trim="false" id="input" maxlength="440"></textarea> and then... <div ng-repeat="w in what">
    <p style="font-size:22px;"></p>
    <p>{{w}}</p>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the value of characters when you update the textarea values, one way is to use a watch like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome";

  $scope.what = '';
  $scope.why = '';

  $scope.$watch('[what, why]', function() {
    console.log('x')
    $scope.characters = $scope.what.length + $scope.why.length;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <textarea ng-model="what"></textarea>
  <textarea ng-model="why"></textarea>
  <p>{{characters}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The character count has to be in another div?

Comment: @Sole you can use it wherever you want

Comment: here is the example code Arun... http://plnkr.co/edit/OFarBYLpDijPAr9QcrHS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

And one more nice ES5 property getter approach which should be better then additional watcher function:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.what = '';
    $scope.why = '';

    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {
        get() {
            return $scope.what.length + $scope.why.length;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" ></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="what"> <input type="text" ng-model="why">
    <div>{{characters}}</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: That didnt work, only the first character gets inputted?

Comment: What do you mean "only the first character gets inputted"? Did you check the demo or you are trying something else?

Comment: Trying to implement the code you have displayed.... but no go... first character i.e. its just stays at "1" for me

Comment: Post your code so I could take a look, hard to help without seeing it.